# UWP Converter design time converter error (Runtime work)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I create custom "BooleanToVisibilityConverter" *IValueConverter*

Converter work in runtime.

In design time have error and no preview.

**The name "BooleanToVisibilityConverter" does not exist in the namespace "using:ASE.UWP.Converters"**

```cs
public class IntToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToInt32(value) == System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter))
        {
            return Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the code of your converter

Comment: Clean and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

If the namespace you want to import is a local one, you should import it this way :

```
xlmns:lconv="clr-namespace:ASE.UWP.Converters"
```

If the namespace belongs to another assembly, you should add info about that too :

```
xlmns:lconv="clr-namespace:ASE.UWP.Converters;assembly=assemblyName"
```

Comment: New error "Unknown type 'IntToVisibilityConverter' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:ASE.UWP.Converters". And build error too.